# How to install Google Application for domain from New Marketplace.?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I have done setup of project using [New Marketplace](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/preparing). When i click on "Test Install Flow" (Api Console) ,one popup is coming, asking for permissions (scopes) to access domain. When i accept "Terms and Conditions" pop up closed.It is not redirecting to setup url. is this correct behaviour.? or It should need to redirect to setup url.

Comment: Same thing happening here. I think someone broke something.

Comment: hi,can any one give any updates on it ? I am still facing the issue, can not go ahead, because of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to deploy an Google Apps Marketplace but restrict it to your domain, you can publish it to the Chrome Web Store and limit the visibility to your domain.

[image: limit Google Apps Marketplace app to your domain]